# Bootstrap 4 Image Zoom with Z-Index

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-transforms

Hoping someone could help me with my issue. I have a small assortment of images that when hovered over, I would like them to increase in size. I have managed this however I cannot seem to bring the hovered image to the front using the Z-Index. Can someone please help me?

CSS (Someone's Open Source Project):

```
    .img-hover img {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease; /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all .3s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.img-hover img:hover {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(2); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(2); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:translatZ(0) scale(2); /* Opera */
    transform:translatZ(0) scale(2);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4 img-hover"><img src="images/Seaview1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 img-hover"><img src="images/Seaview2.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 img-hover"><img src="images/Seaview3.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 img-hover"><img src="images/Seaview4.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 img-hover"><img src="images/Seaview5.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4 img-hover"><img src="images/Seaview6.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 img-hover"><img src="images/Seaview7.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 img-hover"><img src="images/Seaview8.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
</div>
```

Likewise, another issue I kept running into when experimenting was that when I added a Z-Index the images suddenly all collapsed and changed size - The width stayed the same but the height collapsed to a few pixels.

Thanks,

Xeon.

Comment: Probably the height of relative element is small. Could you insert the code snippet please?